# How to Add listview item from another activities editbox in android?

Tags: android

how can i add ListView item from my add activity to main activity's ListView Statically without database?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listviewitemclick();
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}



    private void listviewitemclick(){
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateDel.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Shopping App"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="add"
  />
```

Add.java

```
public class Add extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

}
public void adduser(View v){
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);   
}       

}
```

activity_add.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Add" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/usret"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="UserName" />
     <requestFocus />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/usret"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Contact" >


</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Address" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Total Purchase" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="Add"
     android:onClick="addtask"/>
```

this is the code i couldn't find how to add the editbox value in listitem can u plz help me

Comment: Yes It's possible by start another Activity with startActivityforResult() and when you return to the Main Activity You have to evaluate the Result in onActivityResult method and add the Item which was added in other Activity's EditText.

Comment: can u plz tell me more i am not understanding clearly bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use startActivityForResult(). If you don't want to use that, I will tell you the harder way.

I am assuming that the first time listview is empty.

Now, if you are going to MainActivity from add user, then you just need to pass editText's data with putEXtra method. Below is the code snippet:

```
String textOfEt1 = editTextReffernce1.getText().toString();
String textOfEt2 = editTextReffernce1.getText().toString();

Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key1", textOfEt1); //set key value pair
i.putExtra("key2", textOfEt2);
startActivity(i);
```

Read about Intent class and its methods and you will get idea what putExtra method is.

Now come to your MainActivity:

In onCreate method:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
  Bundle bd = getintent().getExtras();
  String name1 = bd.getString("key1"); //get value by key
  String name2 = bd.getString("key");
  String[] strArray = {name1, name2};
  ArrayAdapter ad = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,   strArray);
  yourListViewRefference.setAdapter(ad);
}
```

Comment: thx alot bro but when i am adding more value it is overwriting on same what should i do for that?

Comment: you have to concatenate string array again.

Comment: bro i am concatenating for suppose i am giving name1 value in array string only but how i can put the same name1 value which is coming from editbox on array index 1 i tries alot but i am failed.

Comment: then you have to use array list